# Should I convert a library with memory leaks to C++11's smart pointers?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I'm trying to correct memory leaks in a "library" and am unsure how to go about it.

Should I use C++11's unique_ptr? shared_ptr? weak_ptr?

```
Foo& bar() {
    Foo* ptr = some_pointer;
    ptr = new Foo();
    return *ptr;
}
```

I've looked up the differences between them but am still unsure which I should use, or whether or not I should use them at all. The entire library uses raw pointers but does little cleaning up after itself.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replacing raw pointers with smart pointers typically
doesn't solve anything.  You have to design the software to use
either effectively.  It sounds to me like the library wasn't
designed at all, which means that there's probably no way to
make it work correctly short of rewriting it completely.

If the library objects do not themselves contain pointers, and
the member functions never return a `this` (or for the ones that
do, like `operator=`, the return value is never used.  You might
give `std::shared_ptr` a try,  I can work, if enough
restrictions are met.  The others probably not, at least not
generally.  There are almost certainly contexts where
`unique_ptr` would be more appropriate.  But `shared_ptr` will
work in such cases as well.  And you can't use `weak_ptr`
without having a `shared_ptr` to begin with,